# Wrong output datatype (results out of range) on equation with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Got 2 arrays:

```
print(arr1.shape)
print(arr1.dtype)
print(arr2.shape)
print(arr2.dtype)
```

output

```
(500, 500)
uint8
(500, 500)
uint8
```

How do I correctly substract one from another so the output datatype would fit the real result?
Doing this:

```
sub = arr1 - arr2
```

gives me incorrect results, because `sub.dtype` is `uint8`, so it can't fit negative values (when arr2 value is bigger than arr1).

What is the best way to deal with that?

PS. This is only a basic example, the real equation is much more complicated, but fails on this step.

Comment: If you do `out=np.empty(arr1.shape, np.int16); np.subtract(arr1, arr2, out=out)`, do you get the right answer?

Comment: it is not the solution for me, because I can't convert all the equation parts to numpy functions... I need to use `a - b`

Comment: `np.subtract` is literally the implementation of the `-` operator for numpy arrays. You're already using it. Once the types are right, you can go back to the normal flow of code.

Comment: my real equation is more like `a * b / np.exp((c - h)) + (d + z) / (y - h) ...` and much longer... converting it to this type of function will be a real trouble

Comment: You only need one or two temp arrays to be converted to a signed type before you proceed normally. I'm guessing that most of those are already floats anyway.

Comment: is it the only way? doesn't look too clean :(

Comment: Let's start with, does it work even for your toy example? I'm on mobile, so can't test. If it works, this is the cleanest approach, even though it admittedly looks like crap. If not, I'll show you another.

Comment: yes, the `out=` thingy works

Comment: I have also noticed that `numexpr` has no such a problem

Comment: Yeah, I bet it doesn't. It's like hitting a nail with a jackhammer though

Comment: `np.subtract(arr1, arr2, dtype='int16')` also works

Comment: @hpaulj no it doesn't... in my case it gives 0 on negative values

Comment: @MadPhysicist in fact using np.subtract to outer object on every subtraction is more like hitting a nail with a jackhammer imo... btw '+' and '*' are also having problems, the only operiation that changes the dtype is divide ('/') and it changes always to float64

Answer (score 0):

A very general approach would be to just cast your arrays to whatever output type you're planning on using:

```
arr1 = arr1.astype(float)
arr2 = arr2.astype(float)
sub = arr1 - arr2
```

Another, more subtle, approach is to perform only the casts that you need. An operation like `res = a * b / np.exp((c - h))` is actually

```
temp1 = np.multiply(a, b)
temp2 = np.subtract(c, h)
temp3 = np.exp(temp2)
res = np.true_divide(temp1, temp3)
```

All of these temporary arrays would produce correct results with unsigned integer inputs except `temp2`. You could therefore write the offending step explicitly:

```
temp = np.empty(c.shape, float)
res = a * b / np.exp(np.subtract(c, h, out=temp))
```

Comment: I guess in the last one you mean ` out=temp`